# pass object via routeActions to next route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-router-redux

I am using `react-router-redux`,

Let's say I have defined `url` as `/go-here/${routeId}` and i have `routeId`, also data object as

```
 data = {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two',
    three: 'three'
 }
```

using dispatch, i am routing to a new page as below,

```
this.props.dispatch(routeAction.push(url));
```

After navigating to new page, i would like to access data object, How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire an action to set `data` in your store. Then your new page can pick up this data by simply reading this property. A good way to do this is to `connect` (using `react-redux`) your receiving component and `mapStateToProps`.